# ChanSpy + PlayBack + MutingChannel asterisk

Tags: signal-processing, asterisk, asteriskami

First of all this is not a question related to conference call. This is pure 1 to 1 sip call scenario. and during this sip call what I am trying to do is, to play an audio file on either one of them, and while playing audio, i don't want to hear other's party voice.

For playing audio, I have initiate and AMI command like follows

```
Action: Originate
Channel: Local/s@whisper-to-party
Variable: MyChannel=SIP/666
Application: Playback
Data: hello-world
ActionID:11
```

On Dialplan I have

```
[whisper-to-party]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,ChanSpy(${MyChannel}, qsW)
```

Now I want whenever I play "hello-world" to the MyChannel, it will hear nothing except my playback audio.

I tried MuteAudio AMI call too before ChanSpy call, but it was mute the whole channel and I can't able to hear hello world

Any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only way do that is unbridge channel on answer

```
 G([[context^]exten^]priority): If the call is answered, transfer
    the calling party to the specified <priority> and the called party to
    the specified  <priority> plus one.
    NOTE: You cannot use any additional action post answer options in
    conjunction with this option.
```

After playback bridge it back via conference room(it will use simple bridge if 2 party in conference)